# Anthropogenic sound impacts aquatic animals

Tags: sound

Anthropogenic sound impacts aquatic animals.
Are there studies to explore sound effects on Lake Victoria Cichlids?

Comment: Welcome @Fisheries! Please provide more background information on your question (background for your question, and where you have looked for answers). Please see Stack Exchange FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Hi @Fisheries and welcome! Please could you re-phrase the title as a QUESTION? Stack Exchange works as a Q&A system. People should know at a glance which question you are asking them to answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that studies on fish kept in captivity could be a good way to explore such effects in a controlled environment. A quick Google Scholar search led me to the following [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.anbehav.2016.03.027) entitled 'Behavioural responses to sound exposure in captivity by two fish species with different hearing ability' from Shafiei Sabet and colleagues (2016). Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Welcome @Koen! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Could you elaborate a bit on the link you shared.